# how to remove class from preg_match and how to create timestamp

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

i am trying to get 2020-11-05 20:34:38  this data and convert it in timestamp please help

Thank You

```html
<?php
$html = '<time datetime="2020-11-05T20:34:38+00:00" class="time">20:34</time></a></span>';

preg_match('/<time datetime="(.*?)">[0-9:]+<\/time>/i', $html, $d );


//print_r ($d);
print_r ($d[1]);
?>
Output

2020-11-05T20:34:38+00:00" class="time
```

i am trying to get 2020-11-05 20:34:38  this data and convert it in timestamp please help

Thank You

Comment: You forgot there is `class="time"` on the way to `>`. `preg_match('/<time datetime="(.*?)"[^>]*>[0-9:]+<\/time>/i', $html, $d )` will work, see https://3v4l.org/q57I8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to trim `date` from `time` tag , if you are sure about datetime's type , you can try this:

```
<?php
$html = '<time datetime="2020-11-05T20:34:38+00:00" class="time">20:34</time></a></span>';
$pattern = '/datetime="(?<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\+\d{2}:\d{2})/';
preg_match($pattern , $html , $matches);
$date = $matches["date"];
echo($date);
```

**output**

```
2020-11-05T20:34:38+00:00
```

if you are not sure what is in the `datetime` attribute, so you prefer to write your regex in patterns like this:

```
$pattern = '/datetime="(?<date>.+)\s+class/';
```

in order to get the timestamp:

```
echo(strtotime($date));
```

**Output**

```
1604608478
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your pattern to `/datetime="([^"]+)/`

```
<?php
$html = '<time datetime="2020-11-05T20:34:38+00:00" class="time">20:34</time></a></span>';
preg_match('/datetime="([^"]+)/i', $html, $d );
print_r($d[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `class` to regex, like this example:

```
preg_match('/<time datetime="(.*?)" class="time">[0-9:]+<\/time>/i', $html, $d );
```